# Check if Nested Scroll View has stopped scrolling android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-scrollview, android-nestedscrollview, nestedscrollview

I am having a nested scroll view and i would like to know if the user has stopped scrolling down or up. Below is the method that i have tried using

```
nestedScrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener((NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener) (v, scrollX, scrollY, oldScrollX, oldScrollY) -> {

            if (scrollY > oldScrollY) {
                // scrolling down
                Toast.makeText(context, "Scrolling Down", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                relativeLayout.setAlpha(0f);
            }
            else if (scrollY < oldScrollY) {
                // scrolling up
                Toast.makeText(context, "Scrolling Up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                relativeLayout.setAlpha(0f);
            }else if(scrollY == 0){

               // scrolling has stopped
               Toast.makeText(context, "Scrolling Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        
        });
```

Scrolling up and down is working fine but its not displaying the toast for scrolling stopped. Is there another way i can know if the scrolling has stopped in the Nested Scroll View

Comment: `scrollY == 0` means you are on top of scrolling layout, its position, not difference in scroll amount

Answer (score 1):

`NestedScrollView` is a bit limited comparing to usual `ScrollView` (which have separated listener exactly for your purposes), so you have to do it "manually"

declare new `Handler` on top of file (outside method)

```
val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
```

then post to it `Runnable` which will fire after some short amount of time, but before that dimiss all previously set `Runnable`s (in fact one in this case). thus only last `Runnable` will fire 100 ms after `NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener` last call (scroll change)

```
        if (scrollY > oldScrollY) {
            // scrolling down
            Toast.makeText(context, "Scrolling Down", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            relativeLayout.setAlpha(0f);
        }
        else if (scrollY < oldScrollY) {
            // scrolling up
            Toast.makeText(context, "Scrolling Up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            relativeLayout.setAlpha(0f);
        }

        handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)
        handler.postDelayed({
            Toast.makeText(context, "Scrolling Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }, 100)
```

optionally you may pack `handler.postDelayed(...` line in `if (scrollY != oldScrollY)` and in `else` just `Toast` strictly without using `Runnable` (still `removeCallbacksAndMessages` is called before for avoiding double-call, when `else` executes)